# P/Invoke causes crash on method with struct and callback parameters

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I have a DLL from which I need to P/Invoke the following C method:

```
int DAOpen(HANDLE *hOpen, UNIT *flags, void *callback, void *userData)
```

Using the P/Invoke Assistant, I've come up with the following signature:

```
[DllImportAttribute("<libName>", EntryPoint="DAOpen")]  
    static extern  int DAOpen(  
    out IntPtr hOpen,  
    ref uint flags,  
    IntPtr callback,  
    IntPtr userData);
```

The *callback* parameter has must correspond to the following C signature:

```
void CallBack(  
    int event,  
    int socket,  
    struct _iComStructure *plcom,  
    void *eventData,  
    void *myData)
```

which translates to

```
delegate void CallBack(  
    int @event,  
    int socket,  
    IntPtr plcom,  
    IntPtr eventData,  
    IntPtr myData);
```

Now, I'm doing the call in the following way:

```
void MyCallBack(int @event, int socket, IntPtr plcom, IntPtr eventData, IntPtr myData)  
{  
    // does nothing for now  
}

IntPtr hOpen;  
uint flags = 0;  
CallBack callBack = MyCallBack;  
StringBuilder userData = new StringBuilder(userData.ToString());


int rc = DAOpen(
out hOpen,    
ref flags,  
Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callBack),  Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(userData.ToString()));
```

The problem I'm having with this code is that it either crashes or I get a `FatalExecutionEngineError` thrown when I perform a call to DAOpen. I know it must be a marshalling error, but I can't figure it out...

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**

As was suggested, I tried to pin the callback in the following way:

```
GCHandle callbackHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(callBack, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

I get an `ArgumentException` with this message:

`Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data`

It seems to work fine if I don't specify the GCHandleType (i.e. I get a handle), but of course the original problem remains.

Is there any reason why I can't pin the delegate?

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken any steps to ensure the delegate is not garbage collected?

A gen 0 collection could be triggered during your call.
Try either creating a local variable in the calling function,
or manually pinning the delegate in a GC handle.

**Update:**

Also, look at the calling convention
of the callback in the native API. Is it stdcall?
If not, you can't use GetFunctionPointerForDelegate, as it
returns a pointer to a native function expecting stdcall arguments.

In that case, instead of us an intptr, use the delegate type and put an "UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute" on the delegate definition that specifies the native calling convention.

Comment: I've created a class variable to store the delegate, but I still got the problem.

Comment: @XenoAce the callback you provide to native code must be pinned if it survives in native code beyond the pinvoke call

Comment: @Scott Wisniewski Yes, it is stdcall.

Comment: @JaredPar I was under the impression that delegate need no pinning as they are marshalled when performing the P/Invoke.

Comment: @XenoAce the CLR will only auto-pin values for the duration of the PInvoke call.  If the pinvoke call returns but the native code maintains a pointer into native that pointer will not remained automatically pinned and must be done so manually

Comment: @JaredPar Indeed, it makes sense... however, I can't pin the delegate (see my update). Can delegate be pinned at all?

Comment: @XenoAce the problem is likely because the `this` object is not blittable. Try this with a static method instead

Comment: @JaredPar I also tried with a static method, delcaring the delegate static too. It works fine without the GCHandleType.Pinned, but it won't solve my problem.